# Spotify - Skip to next/previous song buttons are greyed out

Tags: spotify

Is there a way I can programmatically enable/disable the skip to next/previous buttons in the Spotify interface?

Right now, they both appear as greyed out. I would like the give the user the ability to move to the next song.

Any info would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the buttons are greyed out is because there *is* no next song — when you tell the client to play a singe track in the Apps API, it really means just that single track.

The state of the playback control buttons cannot be controlled directly from the Apps API - when there are more tracks to play, the buttons will be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there a way to create a queue via the API? Or, how should I add more tracks to play so that the buttons are enabled?